# Spark - how to convert a dataframe or rdd to spark matrix or numpy array without using pandas

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have 20TB of data. I tried to convert spark dataframe to spark matrix as follows ([Solution used found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567989/apache-spark-how-to-create-a-matrix-from-a-dataframe)):
My dataframe looks like this:

```
+-------+---------------+--------------------+
|goodsID|customer_group|customer_phone_number|
+-------+---------------+--------------------+
|    123|          XXXXX|            XXXXXXXX|
|    432|          YYYYY|            XXXXXXXX|
+-------+---------------+--------------------+

from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import IndexedRow, IndexedRowMatrix

mat = IndexedRowMatrix(mydataframe.map(lambda row: IndexedRow(*row)))
mat.numRows()
mat.numCols()
```

but it gives me following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/test/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/home/test/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/home/test/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/home/test/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1293, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

So my question is

1. How can I achieve this in spark?
2. Also how can I convert my dataframe to numpy array?
3. Is using pandas with spark is really bad?

Answer (score 2):

- Types of the input data are probably wrong. Vector values have to be `Double` (Python `float`).
- You don't use `IndexedRow` the right way. It takes two arguments - index, and vector. If we assume that data is of correct type

  ```
  mat = IndexedRowMatrix(mydataframe.map(
   lambda row: IndexedRow(row[0], Vectors.dense(row[1:]))))
  ```
- Is Pandas bad? For 20TB of data? Not the best choice but [there exist distributed Python libraries with similar API](https://github.com/dask/dask).

Comment: I am still working on the solution you gave, also there are lot of nested for loops(5 level) inside which a lot of matrix computation is happening, how much performance impact will be there because of these nested loops and do I need to re-write the code using spark foreach, map or flatmap to improve performance as currently to process the whole dataset it's taking 20 days.